# How to remove a link with jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope to remove the link "ContactUs.aspx" of the following code,  I use the `code $("#Main4").contents().unwrap();` it worked, but the class "LeftMainMenu" is removed also.

I hope to remove only the link, how can I do this?

```
<a id="Main4" class="LeftMainMenu" href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a id="Main4" class="LeftMainMenu" href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</a>
```

This will remove the href attribute:

```
$("#Main4").removeAttr("href")
```

Remember to do it on page load event like below:

```
$(function() {
    $("#Main4").removeAttr("href")
});
```

Or if you just want to remove the value of `href` then

```
   $("#Main4").attr("href", "")
```

This will make

```
<a id="Main4" class="LeftMainMenu" href="">Contact Us</a>
```

DEMO:

```js
$(function() {
   $("#Main4").removeAttr("href")
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

<a id="Main4" class="LeftMainMenu" href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</a>
```

Comment: Thanks!  but when I move cursor hang to the text "Contact Us", the cursor still display the text as link

Comment: You mus do it on page load. Like `$(function(){ $("#Main4").removeAttr("href"); });` Looks like when you're trying to remove the link was not added to the page. That's why it's not removed

Comment: I've added a demo as well to show how it works. Please check @HelloCW

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector is wrong. Should be `$("#Main4")`. You can use `.removeAttr()` to remove the attribute of href. See the documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

```
$("#Main4").removeAttr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `href` you can use

```
$('#Main4').removeAttr('href');
```

To remove only the link you can use

```
$('#Main4').attr('href','');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the link hidden, you can:

```
$('#main4').hide();
```

if you want the link disabled, you can:

```
$('#main4').removeAttr('href');
```

or

```
$('#main4').attr('href','#');
```

or

```
$('#main4').attr('href','javascript:void(0);');
```

By the way, the different href attribute about 
'javascript:void(0)' and '#' is [there.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)